# Google map disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3

I have a .click jquery function when to take the longitude and latitude and pan the map to this point while clicking on the link.
I have tried this but when I click on the link the map disappears only the grey background of the map and the center marker stays.

```
html.erb

<td id="<%= i%>" data-lat="<%= favorite_place.latitude%>" data-lng="<%= favorite_place.longitude%>"><a class="clicks" href="#"><%=truncate(favorite_place.name,length:19,omission:'',separator:',')%></a> </td>

javascript
//When user clicks on the name of any place the map pans to this place.
$( '.clicks' ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var lt=$(this).data("lat");
    var ln=$(this).data("lng");
    var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lt,ln);
    map.panTo(panPoint);
    map.setZoom(16);
});
```

Comment: is map global/ in the same function scope?
also, why do you bind the click handler to the `<a>` rather than to the td?

Comment: Ohh, Thanks alot @Alex when I bound the click handler to <td> it worked  .

Comment: Would you please post it as an answer to accept it or what I shall do @Alex I am a new user of stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the click handler to the td, maybe the propagation does not work as expected here:

```
$( '.clicks' ).parent('td').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var lt=$(this).data("lat");
    var ln=$(this).data("lng");
    var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lt,ln);
    map.panTo(panPoint);
    map.setZoom(16);
});
```